How to update libraries in yocto standard SDK
Right now I'm trying to create my custom SDK image. At the beginning I created my own image and added a bunch of packages to it using: TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK += "<package name>-dev". Everything works fine, all libraries and headers needed by my project are included into SDK's sysroot. SDK installation script is being uploaded to our own artifactory, and it can be used to install it and start the development.
However, each time I want to update the libraries and header files, I need to reinstall the SDK.
I would like to use opkg to update them, is there any way to achieve this? Of course I have all packages(*.ipk files) uploaded to my own artifactory.

What you are looking for is probably an extensible SDK. See Installing Additional Items Into the Extensible SDK and Applying Updates to an Installed Extensible SDK.
